# Swift memcpy doesn't have any effect when used with ZMQ zmq_msg_data

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, zeromq, memcpy

I've been trying to write a libzmq wrapper for Swift by building off of an existing wrapper called [SwiftyZeroMQ](https://github.com/appliedengineering/SwiftyZeroMQ5). However, for our purposes, we require the usage of raw UDP which means we need to use ZeroMQ's [Radio/Dish draft method](https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/48/).

I've been able to successfully write a wrapper for receiving data via the Dish socket but I'm now trying to write a wrapper for sending data via the Radio socket. There doesn't seem to be any stuff online regarding how to write a function to send data via the Radio socket but I did come across [this](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/tests/test_radio_dish.cpp#L56). This function in the libzmq repo tests the sending of data via the radio socket so I figured why not try and replicate the function in Swift.

Here's what I've come up with:

Inside the [Socket.swift](https://github.com/appliedengineering/SwiftyZeroMQ5/blob/master/Sources/Socket.swift) file:

```
     public func sendRadioMessage(_ group: String, data: NSData) throws{
            var msg = zmq_msg_t.init();
            var result : Int32;
            let flags: SocketSendRecvOption = .none
            
            
            result = zmq_msg_init(&msg);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
        
            defer {
                // Clean up message on scope exit
                zmq_msg_close(&msg)
            }
            
            print("initial msg data = \(zmq_msg_data(&msg))")
            
            print("initial data = \(data)")
            memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&msg), (data as NSData).bytes, data.length);
            
            print("msg size = \(zmq_msg_size(&msg))")
            print("msg = \(zmq_msg_data(&msg))")
            
            result = zmq_msg_set_group(&msg, group);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
            
            result = zmq_msg_send(&msg, self.handle, flags.rawValue);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
            print("sent \(result) bytes")
        }
        
    }
```

and that function is then called like this:

```
    public func send(data: String) -> Bool{
        do{
            try radio?.sendRadioMessage(group, data: data.data(using: .utf8) as! NSData);
        }
        catch{
            print("SEND COMMUNICATION error - \(error)");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

   obj.send(data: "Test Data")
```

This is the console output when running the program:

[image: Console output]

It seems to me then that the `memcpy` function that I'm calling from Swift doesn't actually seem to be doing anything. Would this be due to the fact that I'm not passing the data payload properly to the `memcpy` function? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: This code is not C++

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The library I'm using has a core in C++ and the functions I'm interacting with are also written in C++. The example function I linked is also written in C++. I'm basing my code off of that C++ function.

Comment: Then it should be easy to see what [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) requires as arguments.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I have looked over the memcpy function arguments. The arguments I am passing correlate to what it states on your link.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `memcpy`.  It only knows to go to the source address and copy the bytes to the destination address -- nothing more, nothing less.  The memcpy doesn't care about the arguments, doesn't check them for validity, etc.   It will blindly take what you give it, interpret it as addresses, and makes the copy.  It's on you to pass the correct arguments.  You would have had the same issue with any C++ based function that took addresses, not just `memcpy`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, that's why I suspect that I'm not passing the arguments correctly although I can't see that I've done anything wrong. I feel like this is more of a Swift-related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API-documented *`zmq_msg_data()`* function is fine & safe to "read" a data-part from a delivered ZeroMQ message.

The context of use & the order of parameters :

```
void* memcpy(        void* dest,
               const void* src,
              std::size_t  count
              );
```

shows, that your code tries to "store" data into a *`zmq_msg_t`*-instance, in spite of countless warnings in the ZeroMQ API documentation not to ever attempt to "touch", the less to manipulate data "directly", but by using member functions :

> *<sub>Never access *`zmq_msg_t`* members directly, instead always use the *`zmq_msg`* family of functions.</sub>*

Here, possibly using [rather](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-msg-init-data) :

```
int zmq_msg_init_data (   zmq_msg_t *msg, 
                               void *data, // <------- payload to load into *msg
                             size_t  size,
                        zmq_free_fn *ffn,  // ref. API details
                               void *hint  //          on this
                        );
```

So the illustrative example might be something alike this :

```
//
// Initialising a message from a supplied buffer
//
// *********************************************

void my_free ( void *data, void *hint ) // ------- a dealloc helper
{
    free ( data );
}

/* ... */

void *data = malloc ( 6 ); // -------------------- a mock-up payload data
assert ( data );
memcpy ( data, "ABCDEF", 6 );

zmq_msg_t msg;
rc = zmq_msg_init_data ( &msg, data, 6, my_free, NULL );
assert (   rc == 0
       && "INF: zmq_msg_init_data() failed, saying"
       &&  zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() ) // ------- a non-POSIX system workaround
           );
```

Also note, that a proposed defense of :

```
result = zmq_msg_init( &msg );
if ...
```

did gave a sense in v2.x & v3.x, yet after moving into v4.x, it started to do nothing , as it keeps in ZeroMQ v4.3+ API, as is documented in due form and shape :

> *<sub>**Return value**
>
>
>
> The *`zmq_msg_init()`* function always returns zero.</sub>*

Some version-control and redesign efforts might be needed so as to keep handling this consistently between the port-version and the actual API-version.

Comment: This does fix the issue of the message not having any data but it doesn't resolve my overall goal. My python program isn't receiving any messages. I think this is because on the dish side (my python program), its trying to receive data by just using the receive function without the use of messages. Do you know how I would send data without using messages?

Comment: Glad it helped @RichardWei