# ZeroMQ RADIO socket send doesn't have an option for setting a group

Tags: python, c++, swift, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to implement my own Swift wrapper for ZeroMQ with support for draft methods such as `RADIO` and `DISH`. I have been able to successfully implement a `DISH` wrapper for receiving data, I have been unable to implement a `RADIO` wrapper for sending data. From what I can see documentation about [pyzmq](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyzmq/) here,

[image: pyzmq send function]

it seems to me that the `pyzmq` library has a built in function that allows sending messages through groups directly. However, when looking at [zmq.h](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/include/zmq.h#L490)'s send function, I don't see any way for me to send a message to a group. I can send the message using this function without any error but the message is just not received at the dish script because there is no group attached to what I sent.

**Is there any way to send data via the `RADIO` socket by a `group`?**

I've also done some research onto how it would be done if I used `zmq_msg_t` because that has a way of attaching a group. So, I used this function in Swift:

```
        public func sendRadioMessage(group: String, data: NSData) throws{
            var msg = zmq_msg_t.init();
            var result : Int32;
            let flags: SocketSendRecvOption = .none
            
            
            result = zmq_msg_init_data(&msg, UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: data.bytes), data.length, nil, nil);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
        
            defer {
                // Clean up message on scope exit
                zmq_msg_close(&msg)
            }
            
            result = zmq_msg_set_group(&msg, group);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
            
            result = zmq_msg_send(&msg, self.handle, flags.rawValue);
            if (result == -1) { throw ZeroMQError.last }
            print("sent \(result) bytes")
        }
```

which comes from my previous [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367000/swift-memcpy-doesnt-have-any-effect-when-used-with-zmq-zmq-msg-data)

However, while the `zmq_msg_send()` function does return a correct number of bytes sent, my python script doesn't seem to receive the data. I know my python script works because I've used a slightly modified version of [this python script](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/draft/radio-dish.py) from the `pyzmq` examples.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Is there any way to send data via the `RADIO` socket by a `group`?"*

When using DRAFT archetypes ( where a SuT is still inside a flow of continuous development, the more any next level derived-artifacts, meaning any derived language wrapper or binding prototype ), one has to accept some level of discomfort, not having stable API, net having a mature API-documentation and we have to become a sort of detectives :

```
zmq_msg_set_group ( zmq_msg_t *msg, const char *group );
```

The native API ( later bent into a more pythonic-looking module ) presents this procedural step ( later perhaps bent into a just another parameter inside a call-interface of the method of a `pyzmq.Socket.send()` ) [has it](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/76849aa3d5055fa0e10b86a8d0acaaf05ce82cc7/include/zmq.h#L712).

Stay tuned & never give up hacking the goal having the only source we have, the native API

:o)